# SATA Hard Drives not found in Debian Jessie

Tags: hard-drive, sata, debian-jessie

The hard drives show up in BIOS:

[image]
[image]

But not Jessie. 
Output from fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232.9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xd098e3b1

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 471623679 471621632 224.9G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       471625726 488396799  16771074     8G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       471625728 488396799  16771072     8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Output from blkid:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="4baeb996-3f9d-4181-a4f0-7da4bb83f937" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="d098e3b1-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="3b9948ed-22f4-4926-9df7-1ca8e77a9726" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="d098e3b1-05"
```

Output from dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000008ffa0000-0x000000008ffadfff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] Memory: 3710744K/3931384K available (5209K kernel code, 946K rwdata, 1832K rodata, 1204K init, 840K bss, 220640K reserved)
[    0.885895] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 8192k
[    0.923593] libata version 3.00 loaded.
[    0.944354] pata_amd 0000:00:06.0: version 0.4.1
[    0.945307] scsi0 : pata_amd
[    0.945451] scsi1 : pata_amd
[    0.945521] ata1: PATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xffa0 irq 14
[    0.945523] ata2: PATA max UDMA/133 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xffa8 irq 15
[    1.060228] ata3: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf4d76000 port 0xf4d76100 irq 42
[    1.060230] ata4: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf4d76000 port 0xf4d76180 irq 42
[    1.060232] ata5: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf4d76000 port 0xf4d76200 irq 42
[    1.060234] ata6: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf4d76000 port 0xf4d76280 irq 42
[    1.060235] ata7: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf4d76000 port 0xf4d76300 irq 42
[    1.060237] ata8: SATA max UDMA/133 abar m8192@0xf4d76000 port 0xf4d76380 irq 42
[    1.109549] ata1.00: ATA-6: WDC WD2500LB-55EDA0, 15.05R15, max UDMA/100
[    1.109552] ata1.00: 488397168 sectors, multi 16: LBA48 
[    1.109560] ata1: nv_mode_filter: 0x3f39f&0x3f39f->0x3f39f, BIOS=0x3f000 (0xc6000000) ACPI=0x3f01f (20:900:0x11)
[    1.125152] ata1.00: configured for UDMA/100
[    1.125593] ata2: port disabled--ignoring
[    1.379875] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.379894] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    1.379912] ata8: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.379927] ata7: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.379959] ata5: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    1.379979] ata6: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
[    6.381790] ata4.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[    6.381797] ata4.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[    6.381814] ata3.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[    6.381822] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[    6.701912] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[    6.701926] ata4: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[   16.705807] ata4.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[   16.705811] ata4.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[   16.705813] ata4: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   16.705820] ata3.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[   16.705823] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[   16.705826] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[   17.025943] ata3: SATA link up <unknown> (SStatus 103 SControl 310)
[   17.025959] ata4: SATA link up <unknown> (SStatus 103 SControl 310)
[   47.037639] ata4.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[   47.037643] ata4.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[   47.037654] ata3.00: qc timeout (cmd 0xec)
[   47.037660] ata3.00: failed to IDENTIFY (I/O error, err_mask=0x4)
[   47.357769] ata4: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[   47.357782] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
[   48.734682] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Output from lspci -nn:

```
00:00.0 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller [10de:0754] (rev a2)
00:01.0 ISA bridge [0601]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] LPC Bridge [10de:075d] (rev a2)
00:01.1 SMBus [0c05]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SMBus [10de:0752] (rev a1)
00:01.2 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller [10de:0751] (rev a1)
00:01.3 Co-processor [0b40]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Co-Processor [10de:0753] (rev a2)
00:01.4 RAM memory [0500]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] Memory Controller [10de:0568] (rev a1)
00:02.0 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller [10de:077b] (rev a1)
00:02.1 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller [10de:077c] (rev a1)
00:04.0 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] OHCI USB 1.1 Controller [10de:077d] (rev a1)
00:04.1 USB controller [0c03]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] EHCI USB 2.0 Controller [10de:077e] (rev a1)
00:06.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] IDE [10de:0759] (rev a1)
00:07.0 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP72XE/MCP72P/MCP78U/MCP78S High Definition Audio [10de:0774] (rev a1)
00:08.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge [10de:075a] (rev a1)
00:09.0 IDE interface [0101]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] SATA Controller (non-AHCI mode) [10de:0ad0] (rev a2)
00:0b.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge [10de:0569] (rev a1)
00:10.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Express Bridge [10de:0778] (rev a1)
00:11.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0779] (rev a1)
00:13.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge [10de:077a] (rev a1)
00:14.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation MCP78S [GeForce 8200] PCI Bridge [10de:077a] (rev a1)
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration [1022:1200]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map [1022:1201]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller [1022:1202]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control [1022:1203]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control [1022:1204]
01:07.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT2800 802.11n PCI [1814:0601]
01:08.0 Multimedia audio controller [0401]: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8738/CMI8768 PCI Audio [13f6:0111] (rev 10)
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C77 [nForce 750a SLI] [10de:084d] (rev a2)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] [10de:0402] (rev a1)
04:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G84 [GeForce 8600 GT] [10de:0402] (rev a1)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller [11ab:4364] (rev 14)
```

Here's the output from dmidecode, it looks like it doesn't complete (the last line), how to fix that?

```
# dmidecode 2.12
SMBIOS 2.5 present.
55 structures occupying 1998 bytes.
Table at 0x0009F400.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 24 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: 080015 
    Release Date: 05/30/2008
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 1024 kB
    Characteristics:
        ISA is supported
        PCI is supported
        PNP is supported
        APM is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        ESCD support is available
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        LS-120 boot is supported
        ATAPI Zip drive boot is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
    BIOS Revision: 8.15

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Product Name: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    UUID: 00020003-0004-0005-0006-000700080009
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Family: To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: XFX
    Product Name: MD-A72P-7509
    Version: Ver1.1
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: <BAD INDEX>
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0003, DMI type 3, 21 bytes
Chassis Information
    Manufacturer: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Type: Desktop
    Lock: Not Present
    Version: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Boot-up State: Safe
    Power Supply State: Safe
    Thermal State: Safe
    Security Status: None
    OEM Information: 0x00000000
    Height: Unspecified
    Number Of Power Cords: 1
    Contained Elements: 0

Handle 0x0004, DMI type 4, 40 bytes
Processor Information
    Socket Designation: CPU 1
    Type: Central Processor
    Family: Other
    Manufacturer: AMD              
    ID: 52 0F 10 00 FF FB 8B 17
    Version: AMD Processor model unknown                         
    Voltage: 1.5 V
    External Clock: 200 MHz
    Max Speed: 2600 MHz
    Current Speed: 2613 MHz
    Status: Populated, Enabled
    Upgrade: Other
    L1 Cache Handle: 0x0005
    L2 Cache Handle: 0x0006
    L3 Cache Handle: 0x0007
    Serial Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Asset Tag: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Part Number: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
    Core Count: 4
    Core Enabled: 4
    Characteristics:
        64-bit capable

Handle 0x0005, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L1-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 1
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 512 kB
    Maximum Size: 512 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Pipeline Burst
    Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Data
    Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0006, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L2-Cache
    Configuration: Enabled, Not Socketed, Level 2
    Operational Mode: Varies With Memory Address
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 2048 kB
    Maximum Size: 2048 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Pipeline Burst
    Installed SRAM Type: Pipeline Burst
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Single-bit ECC
    System Type: Unified
    Associativity: 4-way Set-associative

Handle 0x0007, DMI type 7, 19 bytes
Cache Information
    Socket Designation: L3-Cache
    Configuration: Disabled, Not Socketed, Level 3
    Operational Mode: Unknown
    Location: Internal
    Installed Size: 0 kB
    Maximum Size: 0 kB
    Supported SRAM Types:
        Unknown
    Installed SRAM Type: Unknown
    Speed: Unknown
    Error Correction Type: Unknown
    System Type: Unknown
    Associativity: Unknown

Handle 0x0008, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: PS2Mouse
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Mouse Port

Handle 0x0009, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Keyboard
    External Connector Type: PS/2
    Port Type: Keyboard Port

Handle 0x000A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB1
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A2
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: USB2
    External Connector Type: Access Bus (USB)
    Port Type: USB

Handle 0x000C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: LPT 1
    External Connector Type: DB-25 male
    Port Type: Parallel Port ECP/EPP

Handle 0x000D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: COM A
    External Connector Type: DB-9 male
    Port Type: Serial Port 16550A Compatible

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Audio Mic In
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6A1
    Internal Connector Type: None
    External Reference Designator: Audio Line In
    External Connector Type: Mini Jack (headphones)
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0010, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6B1 - AUX IN
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Sound Input From CD-ROM
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0011, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6B2 - CDIN
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Sound Input From CD-ROM
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Audio Port

Handle 0x0012, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6J2 - PRI IDE
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0013, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6J1 - SEC IDE
    Internal Connector Type: On Board IDE
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0014, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J4J1 - FLOPPY
    Internal Connector Type: On Board Floppy
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0015, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9H1 - FRONT PNL
    Internal Connector Type: 9 Pin Dual Inline (pin 10 cut)
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J1B1 - CHASSIS REAR FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0017, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2F1 - CPU FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0018, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J8B4 - FRONT FAN
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0019, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G2 - FNT USB
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001A, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J6C3 - FP AUD
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001B, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G1 - CONFIG
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001C, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J8C1 - SCSI LED
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001D, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9J2 - INTRUDER
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001E, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J9G4 - ITP
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x001F, DMI type 8, 9 bytes
Port Connector Information
    Internal Reference Designator: J2H1 - MAIN POWER
    Internal Connector Type: Other
    External Reference Designator: Not Specified
    External Connector Type: None
    Port Type: Other

Handle 0x0020, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: AGP
    Type: 32-bit AGP 4x
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 0
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0021, DMI type 9, 13 bytes
System Slot Information
    Designation: PCI1
    Type: 32-bit PCI
    Current Usage: In Use
    Length: Short
    ID: 1
    Characteristics:
        3.3 V is provided
        Opening is shared
        PME signal is supported

Handle 0x0022, DMI type 10, 6 bytes
On Board Device Information
    Type: Video
    Status: Enabled
    Description:   To Be Filled By O.E.M.

Handle 0x0023, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1

Handle 0x0024, DMI type 15, 55 bytes
System Event Log
    Area Length: 1008 bytes
    Header Start Offset: 0x0810
    Data Start Offset: 0x0810
    Access Method: General-purpose non-volatile data functions
    Access Address: 0x0001
    Status: Valid, Not Full
    Change Token: 0x00000000
    Header Format: No Header
    Supported Log Type Descriptors: 9
    Descriptor 1: Single-bit ECC memory error
    Data Format 1: Multiple-event handle
    Descriptor 2: Multi-bit ECC memory error
    Data Format 2: Multiple-event handle
    Descriptor 3: Parity memory error
    Data Format 3: Multiple-event
    Descriptor 4: I/O channel block
    Data Format 4: Multiple-event
    Descriptor 5: POST error
    Data Format 5: POST results bitmap
    Descriptor 6: PCI parity error
    Data Format 6: Multiple-event handle
    Descriptor 7: PCI system error
    Data Format 7: Multiple-event handle
    Descriptor 8: System limit exceeded
    Data Format 8: Multiple-event system management
    Descriptor 9: OEM-specific
    Data Format 9: POST results bitmap

Handle 0x0025, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x0026, DMI type 19, 15 bytes
Memory Array Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0015FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 5632 MB
    Physical Array Handle: 0x0025
    Partition Width: 1

Handle 0x0027, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0025
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 72 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM0
    Bank Locator: BANK0
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 266 MHz
    Manufacturer: Infineon      
    Serial Number: 043E656F
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum0
    Part Number: AET760UD00-370A08X

Handle 0x0028, DMI type 20, 19 bytes
Memory Device Mapped Address
    Starting Address: 0x00000000000
    Ending Address: 0x0003FFFFFFF
    Range Size: 1 GB
    Physical Device Handle: 0x0027
    Memory Array Mapped Address Handle: 0x0026
    Partition Row Position: 1

Handle 0x0029, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x0025
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 72 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM1
    Bank Locator: BANK1
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 266 MHz
    Manufacturer: Manufacturer01
    Serial Number: FFFFFFFF
    Asset Tag: AssetTagNum1
    Part Number: SUPERTALENT02

Invalid entry length (0). DMI table is broken! Stop.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: OK at this point we're going need more details. Like, what make & model of motherboard is this?  Are the SATA ports configured in the BIOS to emulate IDE, or are they set to AHCI or RAID mode (or do none of these options exist?)

Comment: Also, in Terminal, what is the output of `lspci -nn`?  Knowing what SATA controller you have may help identify the issue.

Comment: This is my mobo: http://www.motherboards.org/reviews/motherboards/1801_3.html

Comment: @misha256 the OP seemingly updated the post with the output of `lspci -nn`.

Comment: Normally, these problems come down to choosing, in the BIOS, an appropriate mode among `SATA, RAID, AHCI, ALL_GENERIC_IDE`. Did you try booting with each in turn? Make sure you **also** try `RAID`, despite the lack of a proper RAID.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I did not but I will tonight

Comment: It is possible (just possible) that,as you try this, you manage to make the SATA visible, while the IDE disk disappears. If so, take a depp breath, there are ways around this.  Don't panic.

Comment: I tried all three (SATA, RAID, and AHCI), and none of them worked. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In the BIOS, the SATA mode was set to "SATA" (as opposed to "RAID" or "AHCI"); I switched the mode to "AHCI" only this time I noticed an additional setting pop up which enables/disables Linux support (by default "disabled"). I enabled this setting, booted back up, and now the SATA drives show up.